# How to build helper function for ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following example

```r
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Petal.Length)) +
    geom_point(size=.1) +
    coord_fixed()
```

Since I want to build many similar plots, I'd like to abstract away the point layer and the coordinate system configuration into little helper function:

```r
my_helper = function(pointSize=.1){
    geom_point(size=pointSize) +
    coord_fixed()
}


ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Petal.Length)) + my_helper()
```

The code from above fails with `Error: Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?`

I understand that it can not work that way, but what would be the correct approach to implement such a helper function that follows the ggplot compositional pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like Jimbou's answer, which would probably the most practical solution. But for people coming here with similar questions, I just would like to leave a few comments with some explanation on why `+` is a bit finnicky and how to get it to work with your own functions.

As some of you might know, ggplot uses an object oriented programming layout for performing tasks, which means that objects have classes that have methods associated with them. Adding something to ggplot with the `+` operator invokes the `ggplot_add()` method for the class you are trying to add. For example, if we look at the method for adding scales we would see the following:

```
> ggplot2:::ggplot_add.Scale
function (object, plot, object_name) 
{
    plot$scales$add(object)
    plot
}
```

Where we can see that the plot object itself contains functions to incorporate your scale object into the plot.

Now to get your helper to work with the `+` operator, we would have to write a class and method for adding the output of your helper to a plot. We'll start by adding a class to your helper function's output:

```
my_helper = function(pointSize=.1) {
  structure(list(point = geom_point(size=pointSize),
                 coord = coord_fixed()),
            class = "myhelper")
}
```

Next we would need to define a `ggplot_add` method for objects of the class `myhelper`. We are not doing anything too fancy, we'll just borrow the already existing functions for the objects' classes that you have as output of `my_helper()`. These functions are not typically exported from the ggplot2 package to namespaces, so you would have to use the `:::` operator to get to them.

```
ggplot_add.myhelper <- function(object, plot, objectname) {
  plot <- ggplot2:::ggplot_add.Layer(object$point, plot)
  plot <- ggplot2:::ggplot_add.Coord(object$coord, plot)
  plot
}
```

The important bit here is that the function name has this format: `functionname.classname`, which allows the S3 object system to recognise that this function is a method that belongs to that class.
With this method added to your environment, you should now be able to simply do the following:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Petal.Length)) + 
  my_helper()
```

And in my case, that worked.

More info on the S3 class system: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html

Comment: If it were not for the mandatory brackets which break the flow imho, I'd also consider  Jimbou's more pragmatic answer as more relevant. However, even if your answer requires more technical boilerplate code, it provides a more elegant solution, which is also more inline with my question's focus on how to mimic the compositional pattern of ggplot for a helper function.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is the evaluation of `+` in the function since this is successfully working

```
my_helper = function(pointSize=.1){
   geom_point(size=pointSize)   
}
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Petal.Length)) + my_helper()
```

so you have to find another solution like this for instance:

```
my_helper2 <- function(..., pointSize=.1) {
 require(purrr)
 reduce(list(..., geom_point(size=pointSize), coord_fixed()), .f =`+`)
}
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Petal.Length)) %>% my_helper2()
```

Source: https://rpubs.com/hadley/97970

you can also try

```
library(tidyverse)
my_helper = function(plot, pointSize=.1){
  plot + 
  geom_point(size=pointSize) +
    coord_fixed()
}
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Petal.Length)) %>% my_helper()
```

and further on

```
{ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Petal.Length)) + 
        ylab("new yaxis text")} %>% 
 my_helper()
```

Comment: Can you explain why you wrap `ggplot(...` in `{}`?

Comment: This will first generate the plot, then it will piped to the helper function. Otherwise you can't combine `+` and `%>%`

Comment: Indeed, because of operator presedence (see https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html), the pipe op outranks the plus, and thus we need the rather awkward brackets.